# C++ find_if() cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Client' to 'Client &'

Tags: c++

The following is giving me an error. It's highlighting 'm' in return m->GetAddress() and giving the error:

> Error 1   error C2662: 'RakNet::SystemAddress Client::GetAddress(void)'
>   : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Client' to 'Client &'

I'm not really following why I'm getting this error.

```
list<Client*> battleQueue;

if (find_if(battleQueue.begin(), battleQueue.end(), [packet](const Client* m) -> bool { return m->GetAddress() == packet.systemAddress; }) == battleQueue.end())
{
}
```

Comment: Make `GetAddress` `const`.

Comment: const SystemAddress GetAddress(); I get the same error

Comment: not at the beginning, at the end as chris wrote

Comment: Would be nice to see reasons as to why the down vote.

Comment: Not sure why downvoted? I was struggling with this. Saved my time. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented, you pass `m` as a pointer to a `const` object to your lambda:  `const Client* m`

The compiler is complaining that `GetAddress()` is a **non-const** member function (it is trying to get a `Client&` from the `this` pointer) trying to access a const object.

Make the `GetAddress()` method `const`:

```
... GetAddress() const;
```